# How to remove controls with runat="server" specified in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-controls

I have a webpage with server accessible controls, see 'FileIconLink' below:

```
<body>
    <p class="FirstTitle style5">Downloads:</p>
    <div id="BreadcrumbDiv">
        <p style="padding-left:5px; ">Page Loading...</p>
    </div><!--/BreadcrumbDiv-->
    <div id="DirLinksDiv">
        <p><span class="SecondTitle">Files:</span></p>
            <a runat="server" href="#" id="FileIconLink">File</a>
            <% WriteFileLinks(); %>
        <p><span class="SecondTitle">Folders:</span></p>
            <a runat="server" href="#" id="FolderIconLink">Folder</a>
    </div><!--/DirLinksDiv-->
</body>
<%RemoveHTMLTemplates(); %>
```

Both 'FileIconLink' and 'FolderIconLink' are templates of web controls which are copied by my code - such as `<% WriteFileLinks(); %>` above. How could these templates be permanently removed from the web page at run-time on the server without causing the error:

*The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).*

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What in the world are you trying to do? I cannot figure out what you are doing whatsoever. What is inside `WriteFileLinks` and `RemoveHTMLTemplates`? Provide that code and it might make a little more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately I realised my approach was wrong, as Cade Roux was alluding to, I needed to make up my mind where the templates were going to be used.

My solution was as follows:

- Make controls for containing the results of my (previously inline) code.
- Use templates in Page_Load to fill the controls described above.
- Delete templates in Page_Load.
- Do nothing inline.

Answer (score 3):

This is because you have <% %> inside the control you're trying to change. Instead of  using <% %> in the aspx page, I would modify the code behind to add a literal control or something to the div, like:

```
DirLinks.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(WriteFile()));
```

You should then be able to modify your control form the code behind.

Answer (score 2):

Your inline code is executed during render.

But you probably want to get rid of the templates during Load.

Which means that the two techniques conflict.

Comment: @James I'm not 100% sure what you are trying to achieve.  Presumably because they have runat=server you can see them during the page lifecycle after load and clone them or something?  I'd like to see WriteFileLinks();  If you just set the control's visible=false, the control won't be rendered to the client at all, but there are features like repeater controls which have built-in templating features.

Answer (score 1):

The Page object has another function apart from Page_Load function called Page_PreRender, this function gets executed before Page_Load. So please try remove logic in this Page_PreRender function.
Please refer this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.prerender.aspx